# Automatic constructor inheritance in C++20

Tags: c++, class, constructor, c++20

I just have this code, and I wonder why this code compiles in C++20 and later, but it doesn't compile in C++17 and earlier.

```
struct B {
  B(int){};
};

struct D : B {
};

int main() {

  D d = D(10);

}
```

I know that inheriting constructors is a C++11 feature. But class `D` doesn't inherit the `B::B(int)` constructor, even though this line `D d = D(10);` compiles. My question is, why does it compile only in C++20 and not in C++17? Is there a quote to the C++ standard that applies here?

I am using g++11.2.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++20 added the ability to initialize aggregates using parentheses; see [P0960](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0960r3.html). Previously, you could have initialized `d` using `D d{10};`; now you can do the same thing with parentheses instead of braces. The class `D` does not implicitly inherit constructors from `B`.

Answer (score 4):

Since `struct D` is an aggregate type, before C++20 you could not use `()` for initialization such as `D(10)`.

Thanks to [P0960](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0960r3.html), now in C++20 you can initialize aggregates from a parenthesized list of values. Note that currently, only later versions of [GCC-10 and MSVC-19.28](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20) implement this feature, for Clang it will [still complain](https://godbolt.org/z/KfWMrPdda)

```
<source>:15:9: error: no matching conversion for functional-style cast from 'int' to 'D'
  D d = D(10);
        ^~~~
```

Comment: "*Since `struct D` is an aggregate type*" - is it, though? [According to this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), `struct B` is not an aggregate since it has a user-provided constructor. So, is `struct D` an aggregate if it derives from a non-aggregate? I'm guessing so, since `struct D` doesn't have any user-provided or inherited constructor of its own?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yes, it is. A `std::array<std::string, 4>` is still an aggregate even though it aggregates types that are *not* aggregates. This is no different from a base class. Base classes do not give derived classes constructors by default.